# how to fetch the parquet file metadata using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using python **pyarraow** API to read parquet file. However, this is becoming bottleneck as we have huge amount of file and taking a lot of time.

is there a way I can get this `created_by` column using spark ?

```py
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
table_id_stg = table + '_stg'
logging.info("Reading the metadata for file %s of table %s and Project %s", file_locs, table, project)
meta_data = pq.read_metadata(file_locs, filesystem=fs).to_dict()
if 'parquet-mr' in meta_data['created_by']:
    query = f"UPDATE `{project}.{table_id_stg}` SET time_zone='{est_timezone}' where file_loc='{file_locs}'" else:
    query = f"UPDATE `{project}.{table_id_stg}` SET time_zone='{utc_timezone}' where file_loc='{file_locs}'"
```